# Is "look in" an intransitive phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I saw the sentence as below:

*I thought I might look in on Bob on my way to the shops.*

So I thought `look in` is an intransitive phrasal verb otherwise it would be "I thought I might look in Bob on my way to the shops.". Am I right?

Comment: Are you right about *what?* There's nothing wrong with the text you cited (with / without any / all of the preposition-based adverbial elements ***on** Bob, **on** my way, **to** the shops*).

Comment: ...is it really "useful" to classify ***look in, call in, pop in, drop in, call by, drop by, stop by,...*** as "phrasal verbs"?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I just wanna know that whether or not `look in` is an intransitive phrasal verb since there's not a noun following it in the sentence.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. In what way does it help you to know whether any/all of my highlighted word pairs are "phrasal verbs" or not? Specifically, ***do you actually understand the meaning*** of the sentence you've cited in your question?

Comment: ...anyway, here's [an explicit definition from macmillandictionary:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-visit-a-person-or-place-or-to-be-visited-by-someone) **look in** PHRASAL VERB *to visit someone for a short time on your way to another place, especially if they are ill or may need help*.

Comment: I know it's a phrasal verb that has the meaning of visiting someone, but what it differs to `visit` is that `visit` is a transitive verb that requires an object but `look in` isn't. It's very important to prevent me from writing some sentences like **I might look in Bob**. Unfortunately, if a phrasal verb is transitive or intransitive isn't labeled in the [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look-in) as other verbs do, which confused me a lot. I'm really sorry for my ambiguous expression to confuse you.

Comment: And if I have any mistakes in the question or comments, correct them, please. 
Have a nice day :)